# How can i implement Tree Data Mode from Ag-grid in my Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I wanna use the Tree Data Mode of Ag-Grid to group elements
hierarchically. I tried using the example from: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/tree-data/#pivot-and-row-grouping-with-tree-data with the `orgHierarchy` object only, to define the paths. Just like this:

```
this.rowData = [
  {
    orgHierarchy: ['Erica Rogers'],
  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: ['Erica Rogers', 'Malcolm Barrett'],
  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: ['Erica Rogers', 'Malcolm Barrett', 'Esther Baker'],
   
  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Esther Baker',
      'Brittany Hanson',
    ],
   
  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Esther Baker',
      'Brittany Hanson',
      'Leah Flowers',
    ],
  
  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Esther Baker',
      'Brittany Hanson',
      'Tammy Sutton',
    ],
  
  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Esther Baker',
      'Derek Paul',
    ],

  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: ['Erica Rogers', 'Malcolm Barrett', 'Francis Strickland'],

  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Francis Strickland',
      'Morris Hanson',
    ],
  
  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Francis Strickland',
      'Todd Tyler',
    ],

  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Francis Strickland',
      'Bennie Wise',
    ],

  },
  {
    orgHierarchy: [
      'Erica Rogers',
      'Malcolm Barrett',
      'Francis Strickland',
      'Joel Cooper',
    ],
 
  },
];
```

In plunker works correctly, but, when i try to run it in my project shows me the error:

```
    core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at GroupStage.push../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping/dist/es6/rowGrouping/groupStage.js.GroupStage.createGroup (groupStage.js:389)
    at GroupStage.push../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping/dist/es6/rowGrouping/groupStage.js.GroupStage.getOrCreateNextNode (groupStage.js:374)
    at groupStage.js:340
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at GroupStage.push../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping/dist/es6/rowGrouping/groupStage.js.GroupStage.findParentForNode (groupStage.js:339)
    at GroupStage.push../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping/dist/es6/rowGrouping/groupStage.js.GroupStage.insertOneNode (groupStage.js:323)
    at groupStage.js:315
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at GroupStage.push../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping/dist/es6/rowGrouping/groupStage.js.GroupStage.insertNodes (groupStage.js:314)
    at GroupStage.push../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping/dist/es6/rowGrouping/groupStage.js.GroupStage.shotgunResetEverything (groupStage.js:310)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at zone-evergreen.js:705
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:73)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27437)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27425)
```

I already got the modules imported in my `app.module.ts` with the enterprise keys working correctly.

```
    import { ModuleRegistry, AllCommunityModules } from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
    import { RangeSelectionModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/range-selection';
    import { ExcelExportModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export';
    import { RowGroupingModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping';
    import { ClipboardModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard';
    import { GridChartsModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/charts';
    import { LicenseManager } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/core';
    import { MenuModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/menu';
```

I need to know if is necessary to import another modules, or coding any config to make it work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: where is the plunker?

Comment: In the ag-grid documentation link